# Had a real experiment ever been done to demonstrate and calculate the magnetic field of a rotating charged disk? Or only thought experiments?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics

I have been trying to find if a real experiment has ever been done to prove and calculate the magnetic field of a rotating charged disk, whether it's a conducting or a non-conducting charged disk. All I found on Google and YouTube are just thought experiments, so please if anyone had come across an actual experiment let me know.

Comment: An experiment does not "calculate". It measures. So what stops you from measuring the magnetic field of a rotating charged disk? It's not exactly hard to make one.

Comment: The beauty of using a mathematical theory to fit and predict data is  that once the theory is proven correct it is not necessary to measure to know the true numbers. Electromagnetic theory is a well established theory and the results of calculations using it can be trusted to be true if one went to the trouble to measure.

Comment: If a disk with a capacitance of 20pF is held at a voltage of 10kV, it holds a total charge of 2e-6 Coulomb. If the disk rotates 100 times per second (not exceedingly fast), then that's a max. possible current on the order of 0.2mA, which can cause a magnetic field that is not all that hard to measure, even though you would have to be a little smart about it. It's certainly doable, but what for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone's comment.

Comment: I'm planning to do the experiment myself it needs preparation and money, that's why I tried to find an actual experiment done for the purpose of proving the theory, but I did not find any, so please if anyone know about an actual experiment done let me know

Comment: The reason why nobody is performing such experiments is because one can't learn anything new about the theory this way. If you want to move charge, it's much easier done in a wire and you can move much, much more of it than mechanically. That's what electromagnets do. They are producing much stronger fields than rotating plates and all the results are in agreement with the theory.

Answer (score 5):

See Rowland, ["On The Magnetic Effect of Electric Convection"](https://www.ajsonline.org/content/s3-15/85/30), *American Journal of Science* s3-15, 30-38 (1878).  The whole article is paywalled (though given its date it should actually be in the public domain?) but it describes the experiment you're interested in.  Rowland was able to measure the predicted effect to within an accuracy of about 10%;  and I don't doubt that subsequent experimenters improved upon that precision.

Comment: Thanks Michael, are you aware of any subsequent experiments to replicate Rowland's findings, this experiment is very essential and ones would expected it to be done in every physical institute, but I was not able to find any.

Answer (score 2):

This started as a comment on the reference given by Michael Seifert, but it got too long for the comment box.

I have done precision magnetic-field mapping for a number of open-air coil magnets.  In my case, we were interested in uniformity in both the magnitude and the direction of the magnetic field, because we were doing experiments looking for part-per-billion spin-dependent interaction asymmetries, and the magnetic field determines the way that quantum-mechanical spins are transmitted through the apparatus.

For my dissertation experiment, we had three independent measurements of the magnetic field.  First, when the field coils were installed, we took a three-axis Hall probe and measured the magnetic field at points along a three-dimensional grid.  Second, we had a small volume of hot polarized rubidium vapor, whose polarization would evolve with various time constants related to the magnetic field in a well-described way.  Third, we had our actual neutron beam, whose polarization we could measure as it traveled through the experimental volume.  Each of these phenomena depended on the other, and we did a large number of cross-checks to make sure they were all internally consistent.

You have a reference to your particular geometry from way back in 1878, the early days of the theory of electromagnetism, and somewhat before YouTube.  You suggest in a comment that you would expect this result to have been replicated in many other places.  But that's not really how replication usually works.  When an experimental result seems interesting, an independent team doesn't in general repeat exactly the same experiment.  Instead, the other team will come up with a *new* interesting experiment (which may have been in their "impossible" pile for some time) which the new observation or technique makes possible.  The replication is generally not published on its own, but instead a new paper will say "we used the method of X to do something else interesting."

If my magnetic field mapping efforts had *failed*, we would have diagnosed the failure by making maps of progressively simpler geometries in order to isolate the problem.  But they didn't fail.  Advanced technology let us skip straight to the more complicated problem.